# How do I display data only from user defined data type in sql sever?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I have written a query which display user defined types in sql

```
select * from sys.types where is_user_defined=1
```

The above query display data from both the section i.e
**user defined data type** and **user defined table type**. 
My question is:**How do i display data only from user defined data type and not from user defined table type?**
Thank you all for help.

Comment: Is your question about sql server?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, You may try below query -

```
select * from sys.types where is_user_defined = 1 and is_table_type <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I am getting my output. Can you elaborate is_table_type <> 1?

Comment: 1st There is no Sir on SO. and 2nd, This is just another column in sys.types table to indicate whether it is table type or not.